# Set default state in useForm personalize hook with values passing in props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hooks, state

I create a personalize useForm hook for managing all form in my app.
Works great for signin/signup/store, now i try to refactor him for he set default values, when he is called in edit mode.

My problem is when useForm state values are set on first render, the inputs value at storeApply stays empty, because the values return by useForm hook, save the previous state i think, not the updated state.
Because, when i refactor the code in useForm hook for test, the component is re-render and that my updated values are returns to my form.

This my useForm hook:

```
 import React, {
    useState,
    ChangeEvent,
    FormEvent,
    useEffect,
} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import validator from '../utils/validateInfo';
import { store } from '../features/apply/storeSlice';
import { signin } from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import { signUp } from '../features/user/registerSlice';

export interface IValues {
    [key: string]: string | string[];
}

export interface IErrors {
    [key: string]: string;
}

type ActionType = 'store' | 'edit' | 'register' | 'signin' | 'signUp';

const useForm = (
    fields: IValues,
    actionType: ActionType,
    userId?: string,
    token?: string
) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<IValues>(fields);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState<{} | IErrors>({});
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const handleSelect = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        let tech = Array.from(
            e.target.selectedOptions,
            (option: HTMLOptionElement) => option.value
        );
        setValues({ ...values, technologies: tech });
    };

    const handleChange = (
        e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
    ) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setErrors(validator(values));
        setIsSubmitting(true);
    };

    const fetch = () => {
        switch (actionType) {
            case 'store': {
                if (userId && token) {
                    dispatch(store(values, userId, token));
                    break;
                } else {
                    console.error('UserId & token not provided.');
                    break;
                }
            }
            case 'signin': {
                dispatch(signin(values));
                break;
            }
            case 'signUp': {
                dispatch(signUp(values));
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
            fetch();
        }
        return () => {
            setIsSubmitting(false);
        };
    }, [errors]);

    return { values, handleChange, handleSelect, handleSubmit, errors };
};

export default useForm;
```

Here my StoreApply component (i used the same form component for add/edit apply):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import BackButton from '../components/backButton';
import Button from '../components/button';
import Loader from '../components/loader';
import MessageBox from '../components/messageBox';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { setStoreReset, storeSelector } from '../features/apply/storeSlice';
import { authSelector } from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import useForm from '../hooks/useForm';
import { fetchById, getByIdSelector } from '../features/apply/getByIdSlice';

export interface IObjectOptions {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const techOptions: IObjectOptions = {
    html5: 'HTML5',
    css3: 'CSS3',
    js: 'JavaScript',
    reactjs: 'ReactJS',
    vuejs: 'VueJS',
    angular: 'Angular',
    mongodb: 'MongoDB',
    firebase: 'Firebase',
    mariadb: 'MariaDB',
    postgresql: 'PostgreSQL',
    git: 'Git',
    svn: 'SVN',
    'styled-component': 'Styled-components',
    bootstrap: 'Bootstrap',
    materialui: 'MaterialUI',
    tailwindcss: 'TailwindCSS',
};

const StoreApply = () => {
    const { currentUser } = useSelector(authSelector);
    const history = useHistory();

    //Edit
    const { id }: any = useParams();
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

    const {
        apply,
        isLoading: applyLoading,
        error: errorGetApply,
    } = useSelector(getByIdSelector);

    //Add
    const {
        isStore,
        error: errorToStore,
        isLoading,
    } = useSelector(storeSelector);

    const { values, handleChange, handleSelect, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(
        {
            corporation: edit && apply ? apply.corporation : '',
            email: edit && apply ? apply.email : '',
            position: edit && apply ? apply.position : '',
            city: edit && apply ? apply.city : '',
            technologies: edit && apply ? apply.techno.split(',') : [],
            comment: edit && apply ? apply.comment : '',
            date: edit && apply ? apply.reminder : '',
        },
        edit ? 'edit' : 'store',
        currentUser?._id,
        currentUser?.token
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isStore) {
            history.goBack();
        }

        if (id && currentUser) {
            setEdit(true);
            dispatch(fetchById(id, currentUser.token));
        }
        return () => {
            dispatch(setStoreReset());
        };
    }, [isStore]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <BackButton />
            {edit ? <h2>Edit Apply</h2> : <h2>New Apply</h2>}
            {errorToStore.message ||
                (errorGetApply.message && (
                    <MessageBox type='error'>
                        {errorToStore.message && errorGetApply}
                    </MessageBox>
                ))}
            {isLoading || applyLoading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <DatePicker>
                        <label htmlFor='date'>Date Of Recall</label>
                        <input onChange={handleChange} type='date' name='date' />
                        {'date' in errors && <FieldInfo>{errors.date}</FieldInfo>}
                    </DatePicker>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label htmlFor='corporation'>Corporation</label>
                        <Input
                            type='text'
                            name='corporation'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.corporation}
                            required
                        />
                        {'corporation' in errors && (
                            <FieldInfo>{errors.corporation}</FieldInfo>
                        )}
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label htmlFor='email'>E-mail</label>
                        <Input
                            type='text'
                            name='email'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required
                            value={values.email}
                        />
                        {'email' in errors && <FieldInfo>{errors.email}</FieldInfo>}
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label htmlFor='position'>Position</label>
                        <Input
                            type='text'
                            name='position'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.position}
                            required
                        />
                        {'position' in errors && <FieldInfo>{errors.position}</FieldInfo>}
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <label htmlFor='city'>City</label>
                        <Input
                            type='text'
                            name='city'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required
                            value={values.city}
                        />
                        {'city' in errors && <FieldInfo>{errors.city}</FieldInfo>}
                    </FormGroup>
                    <SelectTechno>
                        <label htmlFor='technologies'>Technologies</label>
                        <select
                            onChange={handleSelect}
                            name='technologies'
                            id='technologies'
                            multiple
                            value={values.technologies}
                            required>
                            {Object.entries(techOptions).map((value) => {
                                const optionValue = value[0];
                                const label = value[1];
                                return (
                                    <option key={uuidv4()} value={optionValue}>
                                        {label}
                                    </option>
                                );
                            })}
                        </select>
                        {'technologies' in errors && (
                            <FieldInfo>{errors.technologies}</FieldInfo>
                        )}
                    </SelectTechno>
                    <Comment>
                        <label htmlFor='comment'>Comment</label>
                        <textarea
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            name='comment'
                            maxLength={200}
                            id='comment'
                            required
                            placeholder={`200 characters maximum...`}
                            value={values.comment}
                        />
                        {'comment' in errors && <FieldInfo>{errors.comment}</FieldInfo>}
                    </Comment>
                    <ButtonWrapper>
                        <Button type='submit'>Store</Button>
                    </ButtonWrapper>
                </form>
            )}
        </Container>
    );
};

export default StoreApply;
```

PS: For the context is a personal project for management job application.

Comment: What is the `values` value in `StoreApply` on the first render?

Comment: On the first render the values value in StoreApply is a same object passed to useForme hooks, but each key has an empty value.

Comment: But right, because `edit` is `false` on the first render ->`email: edit && apply ...`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i finally found my error, i set the value of state `edit` relative of my condition in
`useEffect` and not like default value directly when i initialize my `useState`.

So when the component is mounted `edit` is `false` and my default form values are not set because my condition `edit && apply ? apply.corporation:''` is not true on first renderer...

I refactor my code like this :

```
const { id }: any = useParams();
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(id ? true : false);
```

and delete this : `setEdit(true)`  in `useEffect`.

Thanks @Kox to have drawn my attention to this point ;)

Comment: Glad you made it!

Comment: ps you can write that `useState` as so: `useState(!!id)`